# Pypsark: How to Apply Function to Spark DataFrame Column Conditionally and Fill In Null Values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apply, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe with one column in particular `location_string` and I essentially just want to decompose this into 3 columns called `country`, `region`, and `city`. Then I want to coalesce these with the already existing `country`, `region`, `city` columns to ensure that the NULL values are filled. Or put another way, I want to apply my function to rows where `city`, `region`, or `country` are NULL, in an attempt to fill in those values using the `location_string`.

Example Dataset:

```
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-------+
|     location_string|             city|region|country|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-------+
|Jonesboro, AR, US...|             NULL|    AR|   NULL|
|Lake Village, AR,...|     Lake Village|    AR|    USA|
|Little Rock, AR, ...|      Little Rock|    AR|    USA|
|Little Rock, AR, ...|      Little Rock|    AR|    USA|
|Malvern, AR, US, ...|          Malvern|  NULL|    USA|
|Malvern, AR, US, ...|          Malvern|    AR|    USA|
|Morrilton, AR, US...|        Morrilton|    AR|    USA|
|Morrilton, AR, US...|        Morrilton|    AR|    USA|
|N. Little Rock, A...|North Little Rock|    AR|    USA|
|N. Little Rock, A...|North Little Rock|    AR|    USA|
|Ozark, AR, US, 72949|            Ozark|    AR|    USA|
|Ozark, AR, US, 72949|            Ozark|    AR|    USA|
|Palestine, AR, US...|             NULL|    AR|    USA|
|Pine Bluff, AR, U...|       Pine Bluff|    AR|   NULL|
|Pine Bluff, AR, U...|       Pine Bluff|    AR|    USA|
|Prescott, AR, US,...|         Prescott|    AR|    USA|
|Prescott, AR, US,...|         Prescott|    AR|    USA|
|Searcy, AR, US, 7...|           Searcy|    AR|    USA|
|Searcy, AR, US, 7...|           Searcy|    AR|    USA|
|West Memphis, AR,...|     West Memphis|  NULL|    USA|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-------+
```

Example Function for Decomposing the Location String:

```
def geocoder_decompose_location(location_string):
    if not location_string:
        return {'country': None, 'state': None, 'city': None}
    GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_KEY = "<API KEY HERE>"
    result = geocoder.google(location_string, key=GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_KEY)
    return {'country': result.country, 'state': result.state, 'city': result.city}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scala pseudo code

first we need to dropAllDuplicates from df(which will reduce API calls to google service).

```
import spark.implicits._
    case class Data(location_string:String,city: String,region: String,country: String)
    val cleaner = ((location_string: String) => {
      try{
        GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_KEY = "<API KEY HERE>"
        val result = geocoder.google(location_string, key=GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_KEY)
        Some(result)
      } catch {
        case error: Exception => println(error); None;
      }
    })
    output.as[Data].dropDuplicates("location_string").map(x => {
       val toCheck = (x.city ==null || x.country == null || x.region == null) // can also add blank check with StringUtils.isBlank
       if(toCheck){
         val result = cleaner(x.location_string)
         val city = if(nullcheck on result.city value) result.city else x.city
         val country = if(nullcheck on result.country value) result.country else x.country
         val region = if(nullcheck on result.state value) result.state else x.region
         Data(x.location_string , city,country,region)
       }else x
    })
```

we can also do orderBy(desc("city"),desc("country"),desc("state")) before dropping duplicates so that when there is duplicates (one with null values will be dropped).

Comment: Thanks for this - you brought up a good point about dropping duplicates so I can reduce the API calls.